# Why is No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lockerror prompted？

Tags: debian, man, pthreads

I want to check the use of the **pthread_mutex_lock** function, so I execute the command  **man pthread_mutex_lock**, the result appears **No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock**.
I checked the information on the Internet and said that there was a **No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock** prompt, need to install **manpages-posix-dev**.

So I'm ready to install **manpages-posix-dev**（I execute the command: **apt-get install manpages-posix-dev**）, but **E: Unable to locate package manpages-posix-dev** prompts me again. Why?I'm using the debian 10 system.

```
gyz@debian:~$ man  pthread_mutex_lock
No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock
gyz@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package manpages-posix-dev
gyz@debian:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
gyz@debian:~$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
gyz@debian:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 
SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install glibc-doc.
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. To make your answer helpful to a wider range of audiences, would you mind editing your post to include an explanation on why this package is the right one (as opposed to `manpages-posix-dev`), and also use the appropriate formatting for your code example?

Comment: @AdminBee good question,now I just know when I install this package , I can man pthread_mutex_lock function。but I don't know what is the detailed reason.If you know, please tell me.thanks.